# How to hide a div when scrolled to bottom?

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

How do I hide a div when scrolled to the bottom of a page?

```
    <div id="cookieID">
  <p class="cookie-policy">{{ cookiePolicy }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-if="!scrolledToBottom" class="cookie-policy">{{ cookiePolicy }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    scrolledToBottom: false,
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.scroll()
  },
  methods: {
    scroll() {
      window.onscroll = () => {
        const bottomOfWindow =
          Math.max(
            window.pageYOffset,
            document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            document.body.scrollTop
          ) +
            window.innerHeight ===
          document.documentElement.offsetHeight

        if (bottomOfWindow) {
          this.scrolledToBottom = true
        }
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Instead of `v-if` you may prefer using `v-show` depending of your usecase.

Source: [Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom in Vue.js](https://renatello.com/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom-in-vue-js/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 data() {
   return {
     hasScrolledBottom: false,
   };
 },  

 mounted(){
   window.addEventListener('scroll',   this.onScroll, true);
 },
 beforeDestroy() {
   window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll, true);
 },

methods: {
  onScroll(){
   var element = e.target;
   if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight){
     console.log('bottom scrolled');
     this.hasScrolledBottom = true;
    } else {
     console.log('Im not in bottom scrolled');
     this.hasScrolledBottom = false;
   }
```

You can use the variable `hasScrolledBottom`  to hide the div:

```
<div id="cookieID" v-if="hasScrolledBottom">
  <p class="cookie-policy">{{ cookiePolicy }}</p>
</div>
```

FYI, `scrollHeight` have wide support in browsers, from ie 8 to be more precise, while `clientHeight` and `scrollTop` are both supported by everyone. Even ie 6. This should be cross browser safe.